# How to fix "warning : Found row where the auto_increment column has the value 0" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, drupal, auto-increment

I get this warning when I run a mysql database optimization command:

```
warning  : Found row where the auto_increment column has the value 0
status   : OK
```

This warning come at the users table and I am not sure whether it is not problematic  for a drupal database. Mysql has [this explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/check-table.html) for the warning:

> This is not an error in itself, but
>   could cause trouble if you decide to
>   dump the table and restore it or do an
>   ALTER TABLE on the table. In this
>   case, the AUTO_INCREMENT column
>   changes value according to the rules
>   of AUTO_INCREMENT columns, which could
>   cause problems such as a duplicate-key
>   error.

A problem which may be pertinent to this warning is that whenever I try to block a user, I get a server times-out and the request does not take effect. I don't know what query to run to pinpoint the row(s) where this occurs.

Comment: You obviously tried selecting the row with id = 0, right?

Comment: No, actually just run this generic command: '    mysqlcheck -uroot -pxxxxx --auto-repair --optimize --databases the_db'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do anything about this in Drupal 6. UID 0 and 1 have a special meaning in Drupal and need to exist like that, although MySQL doesn't like it (for good reasons). Because of these good reasons, this was fixed/changed in Drupal 7. Some background...

In Drupal 5 and older, the database layer didn't use AUTO INCREMENET because of compatibility with other databases. All such id's relied on `db_next_id()` which had to be called manually before a new row was inserted.

In Drupal 6, the Schema API was added (Allows to define the schema in PHP arrays and Drupal will then build the database specific create table etc. queries). `db_next_id()` was removed and for a few tables (users and actions, mainly) some hackish workarounds were added. This however lead to problems (like not being able to easily export and import the table, as MySQL tells in the warning description).

In Drupal 7, `db_next_id()` was added again, explicitly for tables where a AUTO_INCREMENT (called 'serial' in the Drupal Schema API) doesn't work well. the [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) project, which I maintain for Drupal 7, was doing something weird too with an auto_increment table (re-use of id's to connect unidirectional relationships together) too, which I recently replaced with db_next_id(). So, if you maintain a custom or contrib module which does hack around AUTO INCREMENT, use db_next_id() in Drupal 7 instead!

Comment: Thanks Berdir for through explanation. Do you also have any idea why I can not block users?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal uses uid=0 for anonymous users, and actual users beyond that get auto-incremented UIDs. So this is expected behavior, and I would not expect it to be related to your timeout error. You might want to increase your PHP memory limit for that.

Comment: BTW, I increased memory_limit to 512M but still get the same time-out problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a design error in Drupal, contact the authors :)

Auto-increment columns should never have a value of 0, as it is difficult to insert such a value, hence dump/restore may not work.

They shouldn't use an auto-increment value in a table which requires a row with an explicit value of 0 for the auto-inc column. In general, you shouldn't rely on "magic IDs" in auto-inc columns at all.

Comment: Correct, and it was fixed in Drupal 7, see my answer for more details.